# Setting up the path for Maven 3.0.4, win7

Tags: maven-3

I have been trying to install Maven v 3.0.4 on my machine  win 7 for the first time.I have a problem setting the path  environment System variable I have the following 4 entries :

```
PATH
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;M2_HOME;%M2%


M2_HOME
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin

M2
%M2_HOME%\bin

JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin
```

when I do   `mvn --version`

I get the error:

```
JAVA_HOME not found in your environment, please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your java installation
```

The java -version displays the java version  fine,

what am I doing so horribly wrong? Is the PATH ok?

Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 55):

It is only necessary to set the path to the Maven binary and to the JDK correctly:

```
set PATH %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin
```

Furthermore you need to set the JAVA_HOME correctly which is done under windows like this:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04
```

Be aware of setting JAVA_HOME to the root of the installed JDK and not to bin folder it.
The settings of M2 and M2_HOME is not necessary.

Comment: I did all the steps but still it was not working. But as soon as I used this command `SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04` it worked asap.

Answer (score 24):

from command prompt run the following

```
set M2_HOME= C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4
set PATH=%PATH%;%M2_HOME%\bin
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
cmd.exe
mvn -version
```

Comment: This save the day for me. Thank you. why can't every tutorial for setting up maven just use the cmd for this simple task rather then doing the gui rout. This answer should get more up votes. It's fast, easy and you can't mess it up. Thank you Sin2

Comment: remove extra space from path (before C:\...) in first line: `set M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4`

Comment: thank you it works! For people who get the directory by dragging, do not forget to remove the "" (double quotes). This cost me extra time, It should be exactly like in the answer of Sin2

Answer (score 7):

The environmental variables should point to the installation directory of each program respectively, and their corresponding `bin` folders should be added to the `PATH`:

- Make sure that your `JAVA_HOME` points to the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04` (or whatever directory you have installed your JDK to).
- Add the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` folder to your `PATH` (e.g. by replacing the part with `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04`). Make sure that you use `;` to separate different path components.
- Likewise, the `M2_HOME` variable should be assigned Maven's installation directory, e.g. `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4` and you should add `%M2_HOME%\bin`to the `PATH` (the part with `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;M2_HOME;%M2%` can be removed.

The advantage of adding the environmental variables `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and `%M2_HOME%\bin` on the path rather than the fully qualified path is that it will be easy to update Java and Maven (or to have several versions installed in parallell). All you need to do is to update the environmental variable, and the `PATH` variable will fallow automatically.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue as the original poster.  I checked, double checked, and triple checked everything to conform to what everyone has (correctly) indicated the setup needs to be.  I still got the same error.  In the end, I ran SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 from the command line and then ran the mvn command and viola.

So, for what ever reason, pss's suggestion did the trick.  Obviously, this doesn't really change what everyone else said, because that's exactly what my environment variables look like...just had to hit the JAVA_HOME from the command line.

Oddness.

Answer (score 5):

I followed all the steps but it was not working for me. But as soon i have set the `JAVA_HOME` Path, in Command prompt just type:

> C:>SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

It is working fine in fraction of seconds. Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on local installation. I tried out all the suggested methods including the SET method but that didn't work for me. In the end, I had to manually add another environment variable to the system, and then after that

```
mvn -v
```

gave the appropriate response:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T04:57:37-07:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you are running `mvn -version` from the command prompt, and then adding any missing environment variables from the GUI, it is possible that you just have to reload the command prompt *after* adding the environment variables.

Just exit and run cmd.exe

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a variable of name JAVA_HOME in your Environment and set its value as path to jdk.

1. Right click on **My Computer/ This PC -> Properties**
2. Choose **Advance system settings**
3. Open **Environment variables**
4. Under System variables click on **New...** button and give the name
   as JAVA_HOME and value as c:/path/to/jdk

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Appending that path `C:\programfiles\maven\bin` to path variable in system variables is enough, it will work. No need to add user variables.

Answer (score 0):

Version that I always use. Double click and you get the maven up and running

```
@echo off
title Maven 3.0.5
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\hutingung\Development\jdk\jdk1.6.0_33
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Dfile.encoding=utf-8
set MAVEN_HOME=C:\Users\hutingung\Development\tools\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin
set PATH=%MAVEN_HOME%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
@cmd /k
```