# Path variable not staying set

Tags: java, windows, path

I'm working on setting up my development environment in Windows 7, installing Maven, etc. I've been running into path issues and have read, ad nauseum, [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938635/setting-up-the-path-for-maven-3-0-4-win7) that pointed me in the right direction. My problem is, however, that my `PATH` variable (`JAVA_HOME`) isn't staying set.

When I try

```
mvn --version
```

I get

```
Error: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location
of your Java installation.
```

So, I set it

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Tools\Java
```

and then `mvn --version` works. But if I close and then reopen the Windows terminal I just end up getting the original error. Super frustrating.

I've also added that path to the `Environmental Variables` in the Systems Settings (with the semi-colon spacing, etc) `Path` section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only setting it within that shell. This is perfectly normal behaviour for environment variables - not just on Windows, but on other OSes too.

I don't know about Windows 7, but on Windows 8 if I press the Windows key and start typing "Environment Variables" I get an option to open the control panel applet for editing the user or system environment variables. That's where you want to put it. The right dialog looks like this:

[image: Environment Variables dialog]

If the method above doesn't get to it, you can use the System Properties dialog, which has a button near the bottom for it:

[image: System properties dialog]

Comment: Oh, so I should specifically add `JAVA_HOME` itself to the user variables? I thought I just had to add it to the Path section.

Comment: If it's `JAVA_HOME` you're setting at the prompt, it's `JAVA_HOME` you want to set here, too.

Comment: @Matt: you may *also* want to add maven to your path, but the error message was telling you to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable, not PATH..

Comment: Yeah, that worked. I'll keep that in mind for `Maven` as well. Thank you, I had no idea I needed to set it in the `User Variables` section.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the shell works in Windows, Mac OSX and UNIX and I suspect all operating systems.

Each prompt has it's own environment which is separate to any other process you have running.  You can set a variable temporarily, but this is not saved to disk or preserved because you might set it in a script but you don't want it to affect the whole system.

If you want to change an environment variable in Windows you need to do `Start` -> Right Click `Computer` -> `Properties` -> `Advanced Setting` -> `Environment Variables` -> `Add Property`.

On Linux, you add your SET line to the `~/.bashrc` file

Answer (score 0):

To set environment variables in Windows, go to the System control panel (the quickest way is to right click `Computer` in the Start Menu and select `Properties`), and select `Advanced system settings`, and then `Environment Variables...`

Comment: Yeah, I've done that as well. I placed the full path (semi-colon spacing and appending `\bin` to the path as suggested in other posts), and still...same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System ->Advanced System Setting ->Environment Variables. In System Variables, Click on New and provide the Following:

Variable name as : JAVA_HOME

Variable Value as :E:/JdkInstallions/Jdk1.7  (as on my system)

This should resolve the problem you are getting.